# django extend javascript translation catalog with particular messages from django.po

Tags: javascript, django, translation

I am doing translations in the javascript source files using gettext in a django project.
Currently i have both django.po (1000 entries) and djangojs.po (25 entries) files.
I have 5 common messages to be translated in python files and javascript and i want to have a single translation for that in a single file.

In addition to translation from djangojs.po I want javascript_catalog to contain ONLY particular messages from django.po without including the entire set of translations from django.po

What is the best practice of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`msgcomm`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgcomm-Invocation.html) gettext utility to find messages that are common in django.po and djangojs.po. Given you translated messages in django.po and created, but not translated messages in djangojs.po you can use:

```
msgcomm django.po djangojs.po
```

Translations, comments and extract comments will be preserved, but only from the first PO file to define them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create messages for translations in js files using same domain name as the `.py` files (in your case - `django` instead of `djangojs`). See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#creating-message-files-from-javascript-source-code).

Then, in `urls.py` set the domain name for javascript_catalog to `django`.

Hope, this helps.